# How do i make dir have colors for files/directories like ls does it?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, bashrc, ls

Im running Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm very used to typing dir instead of ls as a habit. When i use ls, I get the directory contents listed with different colors for files and directories, as to be expected, however, when  I type dir, I get the same thing without colors. I am trying to make dir either use the colors ls uses, or emulate it itself by any means possible. These attempts have been tried unsuccessfully:

- dircolors
- Aliasing dir as ls in my .bashrc
- Trying to find where the dir command/alias is located ( I didn't find it, and had no luck googling its location )
- putting 'dir --color=always' and 'dir --color=auto' in my .bashrc, which works once, but subsequent calls do not

Comment: You shouldn't add spaces before and after the `=` sign. It should be exactly `alias dir='dir --color'`

Answer (score 3):

You can alias dir to `dir --color` by adding the following line to `.bashrc`

```
alias dir="dir --color"
```

Adding just `dir --color=always` will not create the alias, but will instead run the command when you start a new login shell.

You also need to restart your terminal after modifying the `.bashrc` file or you can run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note: `dir --color=always` and `dir --color` are equivalent. The default value for the `color` param is `always` when it is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

`man dir` points to:

```
--color[=WHEN]
              colorize the output; WHEN can be 'always' (default if omitted), 'auto', or 'never'; more info below
```

So you're looking for the flag `--color` as you correctly thought.

Fact is, you should't put the *command* `dir --color` in your `.bashrc` but you should create a new alias:

```
alias dir='dir --color'
```

Also, on my system, `dir` colors are exactly the same as `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

For enable color support of ls and also add handle another aliases, you can add manual as default color.

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then

    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'

fi
```

Hope this helps.